# How to output regex matches as many-to-one combinations?

Tags: regular-expression

I'm trying to match two different text patterns in a single file and combine their results. Specifically, I have source code whose structure I want to understand by mapping events to their handlers, e.g.:

```
@EventHandler(MyEvent)
class MyHandler {
...
```

so that the result is `MyEvent -> MyHandler`. This is easy enough to do with something like `(?<=@EventHandler\()[^)]+\)\n.+?Handler`. However, there may be multiple events:

```
@EventHandler(MyEvent, MyOtherEvent)
class MyHandler {
...
```

which could also be split up on multiple lines:

```
@EventHandler(
  MyEvent,
  MyOtherEvent,
)
class MyHandler {
...
```

The last two examples should yield

```
MyEvent -> MyHandler
MyOtherEvent -> MyHandler
```

And while I can get matches like this:

```
  MyEvent,
  MyOtherEvent,
)
class MyHandler
```

I don't know how to combine the two parts.

If this isn't sensible to do with just regular expressions, I am open for other solutions but I would prefer CLI tools. The "correct" thing might be to use the programming language's reflection mechanism but I don't think I need quite that much of complexity. You can assume that all events' names end in `Event`, all handlers' names end in `Handler` and the annotation and class definitions directly follow one another.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can do something like:

```
perl -l -0777ne '
  while (/\@EventHandler\(([^)]+)\)\s+class\s+(\w+)/g) {
    $class = $2;
    print "$_ -> $class" for $1 =~ /\w+/g
  }' < your-file
```